# How to use require() in Electron?

Tags: electron, require

I use for the first time **electron** and **webchimera**. I see this [demo](https://github.com/jaruba/node-vlcPlayer-demo), but I don't want open in main window the player. I do not know good use electron so I try with a server that renders a index page and, after a button click, the player-page.

Client loads from server the index page:

```js
//this is for webchimera
if (process.platform == 'win32')
    process.env['VLC_PLUGIN_PATH'] = require('path').join(__dirname, 'node_modules/wcjs-prebuilt/bin/plugins');


const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
const url = require('url')

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let win

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  win = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  win.loadURL("http://localhost:8888/")

  // Open the DevTools.
  win.webContents.openDevTools()

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  win.on('closed', () => {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    win = null
  })
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow)

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  // On macOS it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
  // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (win === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.
```

The index page contains a link to player page, if it clicked the server responds with the player page.
The server is in nodejs.

Server run in localhost:8888 and it sends this html page:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  body,html{ width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0px; margin:0px }
  #player { width: 100%; height: 100% }
  </style>
</head>
  
<body>
  <div id="player"></div>
  <script>
  var wjs = require("wcjs-player");
  var player = new wjs("#player").addPlayer({
    autoplay: true,
    wcjs: require('wcjs-prebuilt')
  });
  player.addPlaylist("http://archive.org/download/CartoonClassics/Krazy_Kat_-    _Keeping_Up_With_Krazy.mp4");
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But I obtain this error: 
`cannot find module wcjs-player`

How can I fix this?

**PS**:
I use a server only because I wrote it for a webapp before I decided to use electron. It not necessary. I can remove the server and use only the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means the module **wcjs-player** is not installed. Run `npm install wcjs-player` in your console/terminal to install it, that must help and also, you might wanna take a look at [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wcjs-player)